# Groupby count() not working with datetime field

Tags: python, pandas

Im working with dataframes. I was trying to group the total count of records for each date. Data types of the 2 columns used are:

1. date (datetime64)
2. total_count (int64)

```
date         total_count
2023-01-27      1
2023-01-27      3
2023-01-27      1
2023-01-27      8
2023-01-27      1
```

From above, you can see for the above date we should get a result of 14 if we groupby date and use the count() aggregate function. However, I the result I am getting is 5. Below is the code I am using and the result I got.

```
df.groupby('date')['total_count'].count()
```

Result:

```
date         count
2023-01-27    5
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out what I could be doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sum()` instead of `count()`

`df.groupby('date')['total_count'].sum()`

Comment: Thanks Dean. It was my rookie mistake for forgetting that I wanted to add the numbers and not count the records. Cheers